# Passing a variable from one activity to two new activities in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was wondering if it's possible to pass the same variable from one activity in Android studio to two separate activities, I've had a search and cannot see if it's possible or not using intents.

The "shareInt" below is a int which is updated as the application progresses, upon ending the application it is passed to the 2nd class, however I would also like it passed to the 3rd class at the same time as the user is provided with two options. Is it possible?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(1st.this, 2nd.class); 
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("data", shareInt);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When would you like to start the second activity?

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer, the app ends and the user is presented with two choices (A and B), currently A gets the variable but the goal is to pass it to B if the user selects it instead of A. Very new to android

Comment: use an if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do something like

```
 if (select a)
     {
         Intent intent = new Intent(1st.this, a.class); 
         Bundle b = new Bundle();
         b.putInt("data", shareInt);
         intent.putExtras(b);
         startActivity(intent);
     }
else if (select b)
     {
          Intent intent = new Intent(1st.this, b.class); 
          Bundle b = new Bundle();
          b.putInt("data", shareInt);
          intent.putExtras(b);
          startActivity(intent);
     }
```

or if you want to send it to both of them at the same time use libraries like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Comment: Thanks, this gave me plenty to think about and was able to base what I needed form this! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean, let me know if I understand correctly. The user has option A which starts activity A and option B which starts activity B, and you want to pass an `int` to whatever activity the user selects?

If this is what you are trying to do, than it's simple. I am gonna assume that the user is presented with `ButtonA` and `ButtonB`.

```
//if the user selects A 
public void btnAPress(View v)
{
  Intent intent = new Intent(1st.this, activityA.class); 
  intent.putExtras("share", shareInt);
  startActivity(intent);
}

//if the user selects B 
public void btnBPress(View v)
{
  Intent intent = new Intent(1st.this, activityB.class); 
  intent.putExtras("share", shareInt);
  startActivity(intent);

}
```

Be sure to ask if you have any follow up questions